# Assignment of BsonDocument to FilterDefinition<TDocument>

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver, .net-7.0

Asking this question out of curiosity:

I'm exploring MongoDB when I stumble upon the following

```cs
var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/");
var collection = db.GetCollection<Foo>("some_collection");

// IMongoCollection.Find() accepting a 'BsonDocument' instance as input parameter.
var documents = collection.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToList();
```

The codes compiles and runs just fine, but I can't get my head around what comes next.

`BsonDocument` derived from `BsonValue`, but there's doesn't seems to have any overload of `IMongoCollection.Find()` that can accept `BsonDocument` as input parameter.

How does `IMongoCollection.Find()` being able to accept a `BsonDocument` instance as input parameter?

Comment: see what `implicit operator` is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators

Comment: thanks for the link. I'd happy to accept your answer if you can put it as answer 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses `implicit operator` to convert a set of types (BsonDocument, string and etc) to FilterDefinition. You can find some details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/user-defined-conversion-operators)